# Error passing time in a form when using CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, bootstrap-datetimepicker, cancancan

I am using the gem `'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17'` so that the user can select a date and time, which is passed to my controller and included in the model's attributes. However, when I add `load_and_authorize_resource` to the controller (using `cancancan`), I get the following error.

```
argument out of range
```

The error is happening because it is passing the date January 27, 2015, but the date and month numbers are switched, and it doesn't like getting a date with `month=27`, hence the `out of range` error. However, this error is not happening in my controller, and the whole process works fine when I remove `load_and_authorize_resource` from the controller.

How can I get this working (avoiding the error) while still authorizing the controller with cancancan?

I am using Rails 4.1.4 and Ruby 2.0.0. Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:** Adding code.

`damages/new.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for([@car, @damage], html: {class: 'create-damage-form'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <span class='input-group date damage-datepicker'>
            <%= f.text_field :date_of_damage, class: "form-control" %>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </span>
        </br>
    <%= f.text_area :description,               class: 'form-control form-solo-field', placeholder: 'Enter a description of the damage...' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    </br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary btn-md" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`damages_controller.rb`

```
def create
if !params[:damage][:date_of_damage].nil?
  date_of_damage = params[:damage][:date_of_damage]
else
  redirect_to :back, alert: 'Enter the date of damage.'
  return
end

begin
  # auth_time = DateTime.strptime(auth_time, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M%S")
  date_of_damage = DateTime.strptime(date_of_damage,'%m/%d/%Y')
rescue ArgumentError => e
  redirect_to :back, alert: 'Enter a valid date.'
  return
end

@car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
damage_params_with_date = damage_params
damage_params_with_date[:date_of_damage] = date_of_damage
    @damage = @car.damages.build(damage_params_with_date)

respond_to do |format|
  if @damage.save
    format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Damage record was successfully added.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: 'Damage record was not added.' }
    format.json { render json: @damage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

`partner_ability.rb`

```
can :manage,    Damage,         :car_id => @partner.car_ids
can :create,    Damage
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Started POST "/cars/1/damages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-28 22:55:22 -0500
Processing by DamagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gc5CPvSxAjwJfX4ekjEuJ1eZml9aoPxQWPfTBC2/kfc=", "damage"=>{"date_of_damage"=>"01/28/2016 10:55 PM", "description"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "car_id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ArgumentError - argument out of range:
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:289:in `parse'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/zones.rb:9:in `in_time_zone'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:37:in `date_of_damage='
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/core.rb:455:in `init_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
  cancancan (1.13.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:80:in `build_resource'
  cancancan (1.13.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:61:in `load_resource_instance'
  cancancan (1.13.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
  cancancan (1.13.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
  cancancan (1.13.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.4.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:78:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.8) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: can you add code to show how you are passing the date to User model?

Comment: @Haider Added, thanks! The User model is not involved here, the field, `date_of_damage` is on the Damage model.

Comment: and you are getting "January 27, 2015" in params[:date_of_damage]?  `DateTime.strptime(date_of_damage,'%m/%d/%Y')` would return `ArgumentError: invalid date` for this.

Comment: I am getting this: `(byebug) params[:damage][:date_of_damage]`
`"01/28/2016 4:01 PM"`

Comment: the date does not seem to be the issue as far as I can see. Any reason why you are not defining all permissions in the `Ability.rb` class?

Comment: Where are you getting the `argument out of range` error? Do you mind showing us a stack trace? Why are you doing validations on the controller, just add them to your `Damage` model and let `@damage.save` do it's thing, there is no need for the flash errors. I personally think this has nothing to do with _CanCanCan_, but we will only know once you tell us more about the error.

Comment: @Haider, yes I have to two user models, User and Partner, they have separate ability classes.

Comment: @Leito, added the stack trace. I think it is related to CanCanCan b/c it works fine when `load_and_authorize_resource` is removed. I have some of the validations in the controller because the DateTime behaves strangely when it is moving from the bootstrap-datetimepicker to the controller and doesn't play well with the model. If you have a suggestion to improve it I'm definitely open to improving it! Thanks again!

Comment: @jackerman09 let's clean the question a little bit: Get rid of `load_and_authorize_resource` and substitute it for your own authorize, you are already building `@damage` yourself and simplifying is good for finding errors. Post a new stack-trace because it will change. Is the problem limited to the date parsing: Your code should work for the date, at least, to include the time change it to: `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'`

Comment: @Leito, I'm not sure what you mean by 'substitute it for your own authorize'. I am intentionally omitting the time. The parse error is happening because the month and date parameters are switched, so it is getting a month of 28 (which is actually the day) and finding that it is out of the range. This only happens when `load_and_authorize_resource` is present.

Comment: Read more about load_and_authorize_resource: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions. That method is just a shortcut for doing the aurhotization yourself.